# Get event rsvp summary using koala gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I have been able to retrieve event details using

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
@eventSummary = @graph.get_object(eventId)
```

and getting users list invited using

```
@eventSummary = @graph.get_connections(eventId,  "invited")
```

I want to get count for all user invited, maybe, Declined and accepted for the event. for which i'm using

```
@eventSummary = @graph.get_connections(eventId,  "invited?summary=1")
```

which again giving me the list of users only. when used graph.facebook like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/***eventId***/invited?access_token=*****access_token****&summary=1
```

i'm getting the count in result.

```
    {
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "xyz",
         "rsvp_status": "attending",
         "id": "10000000123"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/***eventId***/invited?summary=1&access_token=***accesstoken***&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=100004389574321"
   },
   "summary": {
      "noreply_count": 0,
      "maybe_count": 0,
      "declined_count": 0,
      "attending_count": 1,
      "count": 1
   }
}
```

for just solving purpose i'm getting result using fql, as:

```
@eventSummary = @graph.get_object("fql", :q => "SELECT all_members_count, attending_count, declined_count, not_replied_count, unsure_count FROM event WHERE eid = #{eventId}")
```

But this is not convenient to use. 
Can anyone please help, what am i doing wrong ? To get Event RSVP counts. 
I'm using rails v.3.2, for facebook using Koala gem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clean from the post, which code works, and which is not. Please denote it cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it too, that when you request the event itself, those attendee count fields aren't included. You can use the second parameter to specifically ask for them though:

```
@eventSummary = @graph.get_object(eventId)
@eventSummary.merge(@graph.get_object(eventId, fields: "attending_count,declined_count,interested_count"))
```

The first call gets your "standard" event details, something like this:

```
{"description"=>"Blah blah blah", 
 "name"=>"My Event Will Rock", 
 "place"=>{"name"=>"Venue Bar",
           "location"=>{"city"=>"Citytown", 
                        "country"=>"United States",
                        "latitude"=>43.05308, 
                        "longitude"=>-87.89614, 
                        "state"=>"WI", 
                        "street"=>"1216 E Brady St", 
                        "zip"=>"53202"}, 
           "id"=>"260257960731155"}, 
 "start_time"=>"2016-04-22T21:00:00-0500",
 "id"=>"1018506428220311"}
```

The second call gets just those "additional" requested fields:

```
{"attending_count"=>3,
 "declined_count"=>0,
 "interested_count"=>12,
 "id"=>"1018506428220311"}
```

You can store them in separate variables, or as I'm suggesting above, use the hash#merge method. (There shouldn't be any problematic overlap between the keys of these two hashes.)

Alternatively, you can get all these details in one request by explicitly requesting everything you want.

Comment: thanks for comment, since I worked on this long ago, won't be able to check at mark this my answer. but still, thanks for looking up.